# Does splitting up an active record query over 2 methods hit the database twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a database query where I want to get an array of Users that are distinct for the set:

```
@range      is a predefinded date range
@shift_list is a list of filtered shifts
```

```
def listing
  Shift
    .where(date: @range, shiftname: @shift_list)
    .select(:user_id)
    .distinct
    .map { |id| User.find( id.user_id ) } 
    .sort
end
```

and I read somewhere that for readability, or isolating for testing, or code reuse, you could split this into seperate methods:

```
def listing
  shiftlist
    .select(:user_id)
    .distinct
    .map { |id| User.find( id.user_id ) } 
    .sort
end

def shift_list
  Shift
    .where(date: @range, shiftname: @shift_list)
end
```

So I rewrote this and some other code, and now the page takes 4 times as long to load.

My question is, does this type of method splitting cause the database to be hit twice? Or is it something that I did elsewhere?

And I'd love a suggestion to improve the efficiency of this code.

---

Further to the need to remove mapping from the code, this shift list is being created with the following code:

```
def _month_shift_list
  Shift
    .select(:shiftname)
    .distinct
    .where(date: @range)
    .map {|x| x.shiftname }
end
```

My intention is to create an array of shiftnames as strings.
I am obviously missing some key understanding in database access, as this method is clearly creating part of the problem.

---

And I think I have found the solution to this with the following:

```
def month_shift_list
  Shift.
    .where(date: @range)
    .pluck(:shiftname)
    .uniq
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the database will not be hit twice. The queries in both methods are lazy loaded. The issue you have with the slow page load times is because the `map` function now has to do multiple finds which translates to multiple `SELECT` from the DB. You can re-write your query to this:

```
def listing
  User.
   joins(:shift).
   merge(Shift.where(date: @range, shiftname: @shift_list).
   uniq.
   sort
end
```

This has just one hit to the DB and will be much faster and should produce the same result as above.

The assumption here is that there is a has_one/has_many relationship on the User model for Shifts

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shift
end
```

If you don't want to establish the has_one/has_many relationship on User, you can re-write it to:

```
def listing
  User.
   joins("INNER JOIN shifts on shifts.user_id = users.id").
   merge(Shift.where(date: @range, shiftname: @shift_list).
   uniq.
   sort
end
```

### ALTERNATIVE:

You can use 2 queries if you experience issues with using ActiveRecord#merge.

```
def listing
  user_ids = Shift.where(date: @range, shiftname: @shift_list).uniq.pluck(:user_id).sort
  User.find(user_ids)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a similar way of creating an array of unique shifts from the Shift database? I am doing something similar, mapping the values to an array, and I can't seem to make the merge work on a single database selection.

Comment: @smilingfrog can you share your code?

I will update my answer to another possible alternative

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code sample. Cheers.